# Gnome Boxes ISO Issue

Tags: iso, gnome-boxes

I am trying to open an iso file with Gnome boxes but as I click open it says "Box set-up failed" and the terminal  gives the following output:

```
(gnome-boxes:15984): Boxes-WARNING **: wizard.vala:463: Failed to create volume: internal error: creation of non-raw images is not supported without qemu-img
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out! Like the output says, I was missing `qemu-img`. I went to the terminal and typed:

```
apt-get install qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-bin
```

Now it works!

Comment: 1 upped it it works great :D